# Very small black dots/dents in new pepper leaves

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, peppers, pest-damage

this is my first time posting here and I've scoured the internet for days. This is only a problem on the relatively new leaves on my Trinidad Scorpion and Carolina Reaper. They are small black dots that appear to be about the size of a pinhead and are slightly indented. They may appear as solid bits that I can scrape off in the picture, but they cannot (see first pic.) They also seem to be causing only the affected leaves to curl, one of them curling quite significantly (see second pic) I have been applying dilute neem oil since planting about 1.5 months ago on a roughly weekly basis. Thanks for your time, any help would be appreciated!

PS - In the second picture you may see some white area along with the black dots, I'm not sure what that is either. They are otherwise healthy and are getting ready to flower.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqA7E.jpg